# Java creating a JCheckbox array method that uses an array to populate it

Tags: java, arrays, methods, reference

I am stuck on using Java methods to allow reuse throughout my code. I have an array of strings that i want to assign to my checkboxes. I was looping through these without issue. I need to reuse the data from the checkboxlist in another function so i thought moving the array to a seperate function would be the right choice. This is what I have so far:

```
public JCheckBox[] checkBoxGroup(){
        JCheckBox[] checkBoxList = new JCheckBox[numberCheck()];//set length
        for (int i = 0; i < numberCheck(); i++) {
            checkBoxList[i] = MainForm.units[i];
        }
        return checkBoxList;
//in my main form i have this code:
//loop though and assign to the new method checkBoxGroup
for(int i = 0; i < numberCheck(); i++) {
                    checkBoxGroup(units[i]); //Not working
```

Can you help me in the assignment of the values from the string array "units" to the new method. I am getting a little lost. I have tried to parse units into the method as an array and as a string neither are working. I am sure this is simple but lack the knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for taking the time I have solved it using this code

````
public JCheckBox[] checkBoxGroup(){
        JCheckBox[] checkBoxList = new JCheckBox[numberCheck()];//set length
        for (int i = 0; i < numberCheck(); i++) {
            checkBoxList[i] = new JCheckBox(units[i]);
            checkBoxList[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            checkBoxList[0].setText("Select All");
        }
        
        return checkBoxList;
    } ```

Sometimes taking the time to ask a question helps to solve it :)
````